# What is the new "Answer similar questions" feature for?

Tags: discussion, answers, search, answer-similar-questions

I and a few others in chat are noticing that we get the following message after answering a question:

> Thanks for contributing! Have more to say? [<kbd>Answer similar questions</kbd>](https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=28728661)

[image: answer similar questions prompt]

Clicking the button for that post took me to [this search page](https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=28728661) listing "similar" questions to answer.  I guess that's neat, but those questions aren't really that related, and I'm already following the tags that I'm interested in.  Why has this message/feature been added?

Perhaps this was added to help *new* users who don't have favorite tags find other questions to answer.  In that case, is this really useful versus teaching them how to follow tags?  Should more established users be seeing this message?

Comment: presumably to help newer answerers (especially those not yet familiar with the tagging system) to find questions they might be interested in answering?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Test has concluded, nobody should be seeing this particular iteration any more.

Crunching some numbers to figure out what worked and what didn't.  Regardless, the feature won't be turned on again as it exists (have to add dismissal at the very least, probably much much more).

---

[image: We're trying something new]

#### Short answer:

We're running a test around that feature, to see if providing a simple search for "similar questions" helps people find another question to answer.

It is uncertain whether that feature will stick around at the moment.  Currently approximately 50% of Stack Overflow *answerers* will see it.

#### A more detailed answer:

We've been thinking about ways to make it easier for people to find questions to answer.  We've been working on making search better, playing around with homepage algorithms, etc.

This feature has the following thoughts behind it:

- People are either in an answering "mode" or not

  - So we use "posted an answer" as a trigger for display
  - This has the benefit of *not* changing the UI for people just looking for an existing answer to a question they currently have
- Finding a question to answer is a non-trivial effort
- A tailored search is better than our existing "by tag" pages for finding questions

  - [Just clicking a tag includes answered and low score questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c?sort=newest&pageSize=15)
  - [The unanswered tab sorts by votes, which isn't super helpful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=unanswered)
  - [Finding unanswered, positively scored questions is a power user feature of our search](https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bjava%5d%20answers%3a0%20score%3a0); which many people don't know about

The current test is basically an MVP.  The search isn't very sophisticated (though it is *technically* a little more powerful than what you can do through `/search`), the copy and UX is only "acceptable," and so on.  We'll almost certainly try further refinements, provided the feature proves useful in the first place.

Obvious things to test are:

- Different copy (perhaps customized based on how established a user is)

  - I include suppressing under certain circumstances under this

    - Especially if the "similar question"-page gets other links added, it's possible a person already knows about it and doesn't need to be reminded
- Different search criteria

  - Using more than just the tags at least
  - Perhaps customized based on what we know about the person
  - Maybe even customized on a per-tag/per-question-category basis

We're testing now so we can fail-fast, if this turns out to be a dead end we won't have wasted much time on it.

Comment: I can see how this could become more useful by tailoring it to the user.  However, it seems like this *currently* addresses the "unanswered tab sorts by votes" issue.  Would it be possible to address that directly as well by adding other sort options?

Comment: @davidism It's certainly possible we'll do something like that.  The difference in volume between the two pages makes me doubt that we'd be able to measure the improvement of a new tab directly though, which makes it somewhat lower priority.

Comment: I just encountered this, and while the similar questions were not super interesting for the question I answered, they were rather topical. Overall I liked the list it produced.

Comment: So far whenever I've clicked on it, I found it bringing up questions that are hardly similar. It may be a decent idea, but I'm not sure that it's well implemented at the moment.

Comment: This would be more useful for people who didn't already contribute a lot and didn't know how to find the sort of questions they might like to answer.  It would also be helpful if the "similar" questions were similar, and favour not popping up the message unless the algorithm was reasonably sure the questions were similar.

Comment: This _could_ explain what I found in the "Late answers" review queue yesterday... the same user posting the same piece of code as answer on [two](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7156326) [different](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/7156329), related questions.

Comment: The banner is actually very.. *very* distracting. I already answer a lot, can I dismiss the banner please? Reloading the page doesn't help, editing doesn't help. I could put it in my user stylesheet to hide it, but I rather I had the option to say *thanks, but I'm fine*. Putting it at the *bottom* of my answer might also make it more palatable.

Comment: Just as long as they mark duplicates as duplicate and not paste their previous answer into the answer box. Then I'm happy. If you implement [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/210373/duplicate-answers-should-be-blocked-rather-than-just-flagged) I'll be even happier.

Comment: The suggestion it gave me in my opinion was not similar in the slightest, except it was to do with programming. Either way it wasn't a question I would consider answering.

Comment: It'd be useful if it takes me to places I don't already look. E.g. older questions. I look at `newest` quite a bit, but rarely rummage through the older stuff. (But have tried to be a bit more proactive about it).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, I doubt this feature gets out of the testing phase without a dismiss button.

Comment: I can only second Martijn, please let me remove the banner - or at least place it at the bottom.

Comment: My current mode of operation is to look at *newest*, as the unanswered queue is, as you said, not useful. The old questions are usually not answered for a good reason (unanswerable, I'd say). But spending time in *newest* means more editing and downvoting/closing than answering. A page with good suggestions is a good idea. But what is the metric, exactly? Recent and upvoted with similar tags? Perhaps if you disclose more, we can suggest improvements or insights?

Comment: @RealSkeptic The metric is 0-answers, non-negatively scored, and very recent (4 hours).  I think one of the next step, after this test finishes, is to solicit meta feedback on some improved queries.  Provided the test is a success of course, but initial signs are decent.

Comment: Thank you. Here is a small suggestion: Many times, a decent question gets a bad/insufficient answer, and that wipes it off the radar for people whose usual search includes only unanswered questions. So maybe add questions with 1 non-positively-scored answer (perhaps when answer is older than 10 minutes or so) to your criteria?

Comment: If you decide the feature is worth pursuing, can you please create an employee-written thread describing this new feature so we can discuss it, much like has been done with the [shiny new User Activity page](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/249951/help-us-test-the-shiny-new-user-activity-page-plus-a-bunch-of-new-features)?

Comment: StackOverflow doesn't let me dismiss questions that I cannot answer (something like a "read/unread" like in mail), I get to see them over and over again. If we would have a more personalized experience then this feature would not be as annoying - you could just show the ones that I haven't dismissed yet. Currently it didn't show any questions that were of interest to me, by the way.

Comment: If torn between "making search better" and working on this, please focus exclusively on "making search better", pretty please.

Comment: @tripleee improvements of search started before this, and will continue after it.  We aren't diverting dev resources away from other projects.

Comment: I also second Martijn Pieters' opinion. That banner is terribly annoying and I'd like an ability to opt out of this experiment. I think that the devs at SO will learn as much from the number of people who opt out of it as they will for forcing it into the top of answers without a dismiss button.

Comment: What about adding a new operator to search, which restricts the same way as the unanswered page?

Comment: @Deduplicator [Already exists](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/250626/259867)

Comment: For those of you looking for good questions to answer, the new [beta frontpage](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer&hideReview=on&noAnswersOnly=on) is worth a look !

Answer (score 16):

As a "trusted user" who knows how the site works (used to work?) I don't think this banner is very helpful to me, though it might help new users at finding questions to answer.

However, I actually want to report a bug with it: The banner should not show if there are *no similar* questions to answer. In fact, [this search](https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=28781615) ony showed me the very same question that I had just answered (probably due to a caching issue), and now finds no results at all any more.

Answer (score 12):

I don't find the feature actually showing me **similar questions**.

The questions which are now fetched as **10 similar questions** looks like this:

[image]

The question from where I was redirected to this page is:

[Why does the wm_concat not work here?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16674927/why-does-the-wm-concat-not-work-here?nah=1#28758117)

And the new feature which came on top of my answer:

[image]

Now, if you see the 10 similar questions, they are no way related to the original question to which I answered. It was related to Oracle's `wm_concat` function. All I see is that the new questions are mostly with the `sql` tag. Since the original question didn't have `wm_concat` tag, I believe the new questions are picked with the other tags, mainly the leading tag `sql`.

Perhaps, the feature needs to be smarter than what it is right now. Else, it is just distracting me. I could find and answer a lot of questions myself, which I do anyway.

Comment: No, apparently it just shows recent question in your tag "scope".

Answer (score 8):

For me it is yet another annoying feature that I cannot seem to switch off easily. It doesn't give me any questions that are of interest to me. Even if they were, I usually have some scheme to go through all the interesting tags and using this would just mess this up.

I just gave an answer that took time to complete and for a reward I get a banner asking for more. It feels the same as if somebody just asked question 2, 3 and 4 after I helped him out with his question.

Please let us turn this off ASAP. Don't annoy your answerers or they will move on.

Answer (score 5):

The main annoyance to me is that it looks wrong on mobile (where I do a lot of my answering - thank you long commute) -  On my iPhone 6 I get this [image]

Comment: Also complained about in this question: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286987/weird-layout-when-posting-an-answer

Answer (score 2):

At least for the desktop users, here's a greasemonkey script that I use to get rid of the banner. It is a bit hacky but it seemed simpler than trying to directly inject JS into the ajax that generates that box.

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Kill Thanks For Contributing Box.
// @namespace   StackOverflow
// @description Remove annoying Thanks For Contributing box.
// @include     http://stackoverflow.com/*
// @version     1
// @grant GM_log
// ==/UserScript==
Kill = function() {
var Elements = document.getElementsByClassName('next-answer-hook-container');
for (var i = Elements.length; i--; ) {
  Elements[i].remove();
}
setTimeout(Kill, 100);
};

Kill();
```