# If 'Answer Similar Questions' is kept, offer an opt-out

Tags: feature-request, answer-similar-questions

As many will know, there's a new [Answer Similar Questions feature being trialled](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for).

I'm not arguing against the feature in general (or for, I don't have an opinion either way), but for me, the new box is simply noise and something more to scroll past. If the feature is kept, please include a means by which answerers can opt-out.

Comment: Maybe simply hide it for users with more than X rep (or Y answers or something) - they probably already know how to look for things to answer already. (And there are already features that get disabled on rep thresholds.)

Comment: I just [commented the exact same thing](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for#comment159693_286915) on Kevin's answer.

Comment: @Mat: It *should* be able to do a better search than possible manually. Whether it actually does it... Anyway, just making it lots less intrusive might help.

Comment: *I don't have an opinion either way* - Actually you do :P... I agree, that banner is actually quite irritating.. *I know where to find the right questions* :P

Comment: @TheLostMind: :-) No, really, I just haven't given it thought in terms of how it might be useful (or might not) for *other* answerers. It's not useful for *me*, but that doesn't mean it's necessarily not useful. (I do admit that I lean that way *not* having throught about it deeply, though.)

Comment: Maybe it should be "Flag a similar question as duplicate"

Comment: @AntonyD'Andrea: That comment would probably be more appropriate [over here on the feature announcement page](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for).

Comment: While we're at it, i'd like to have the ability to opt out of the "Featured on Meta" sidebar, the "Browse other questions tagged..." line, and the "horizontal rule" button in the edit box. I don't personally use them very much, so their presence on my screen is an affront to human dignity.

Comment: @Sneftel, the fact that the edit box snatches `CTRL-R` for a horizontal rule is quite obnoxious. The button doesn't bother me personally.