# Weird layout when posting an answer

Tags: bug, design, mobile-web, answer-similar-questions

When posting a new answer using the mobile website, the [new `Answer similar questions` box](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for) breaks the layout.

[image: screenshot]

Can this be fixed please?

Comment: Also complained about here: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/287102