# Help build a good "Find The Next Question To Answer" query

Tags: discussion, answers, search, answer-similar-questions

Some of you may recall an experiment I ran a month or so ago, the ["Answer Similar Questions" hook](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for/286915#286915). It didn't work quite like we'd hoped, but the data suggest there's some promise there.

The quality of the search in the experiment was quite poor, which was noted both here on Meta and in subsequent analysis of the results. I believe before anything else is tried, we have to nail down a better search.

Rather than just make our best guess search and then <strike>subject everyone to it</strike> test it, we're going to try [something we've done before](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69571/help-us-choose-a-sort-order-for-the-stack-overflow-homepage) and tap Meta's answering know-how to build it.

#### Help us build a good "Find the Next Question to Answer" search

I've [thrown together a little page](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer) that lets any logged-in Stack Overflow user twist the knobs on our search service. The goal is to produce a search which, given *just your* recently-answered question, produces a small list of questions that you might want to answer.

[image]
<sub>[Programmer UI at its finest](http://blog.codinghorror.com/this-is-what-happens-when-you-let-developers-create-ui/)</sub>

#### The query builder interface

We're using [Elasticsearch](http://www.elastic.co/guide/) here, so those of you familiar with it will recognize a lot of these options:

- **Question/Answer Link** - indicates the question to use as input, and isn't strictly part of the query (it won't be saved).
- **Like Query** - choose the method Elastic uses to find similar posts

  - **More like this** - corresponds to a [more like this query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-mlt-query.html). It is based on question titles, with various analyzers applied.
  - **Fuzzy like this** - corresponds to a [fuzzy like this query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-flt-query.html). It is also based on question titles.
- **Tag Impact** - how to consider tags.

  - **Require primary tag** - all results *must* have the first tag on the provided question.
  - **Boost any shared tag** - the applies a boost for each tag in common with the provided question.
  - **Require primary tag and boost other shared tags** - a combination of the two prior.  The primary tag is required, and any *other* tags in common with the provided question get a configurable boost.
- **No older than** - will filter out any questions older than the given number of hours (the rationale being that maybe old unanswered questions are unanswered for a reason).
- And finally the **Additional Ranking Function** - this takes an infix function (basic operators `+`, `-`, `*`, `/`, function calls, and grouping with `()`; no variables or anything fancy), which is calculated for each question, and then multiplied with the standard Elasticsearch document score. It corresponds to a [function score query](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.x/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

  - A set of parameters, using a `@` sigil, are also provided for use in the Ranking Function: those prefixed by `AQ` refer to the passed/"just answered" question and are constant for a query's run, while those prefixed by `UQ` refer to the under-consideration/"unanswered" question, and will vary.
  - There are 7 more parameters which are special cases:
  - `@DefaultSearchScore` is the score Elasticsearch would assign to the document in the absence of the ranking function.
  - `@UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnAQ` is the sum of scores (upvotes - downvotes) the user has on other answers to questions with any of the same tags as the provided question
  - `@UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnUQ` is the same, but for the questions being searched
  - `@UserAnswerScoreInTagsCommon` is the same, but for the tags in common between the provided question and the questions being searched
  - `@UserAnswerCountInTagsOnAQ` is the count of all answers the user has on other questions with any of same tags as the provided question
  - `@UserAnswerCountInTagsOnUQ` is the same, but for the questions being searched
  - `@UserAnswerCountInTagsCommon` is the same, but for the the tags in common between the provided question and the questions being searched

These are the knobs we think matter most, but **if you can make a case for another parameter or option, please do so as a comment to this question!** Note that some things won't be possible due to how we index questions.

The following constraints that are applied to all queries:

- Because we're only trying to surface a few questions as options, this page only returns the top 5 results of the search
- Questions must be in a "normal"-state, not locked, closed, deleted, etc.
- Questions must have a score >= 0
- Questions must be unanswered (have 0 undeleted answers)
- For safety reasons, there's a throttle (1 query every 30 seconds), but since I've been evaluating each question for its "answer-ability" I haven't found that too onerous.

Please save any promising queries, and post links and details as answers to this question. [A link to a query, saved from the example show above](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=fb756545-a795-4f68-9077-35d1b5a0a197).

---

## Update:

this interface has been disabled, the winning(-est) query was proposed by [Travis J](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j) in [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/289709/80572).  Analysis showed an increase in second answer rate, and that the answers so posted were typically better (as measured by reception w.r.t. voting).

The actual "next answer suggestion"-feature remains disabled while final adjustments are made (exposing the dismissal setting, tweaks around answer flow, changes to prompting logic, etc.).  I'll probably be posting again in the coming weeks with the final-ish design.

Comment: I was just wondering where that sticky note went.

Comment: Out of curiosity, can we use the same thing on a question we just voted to close?

Comment: @Jongware if we get a decent search out of this experiment, we'll probably rub it against a bunch of different problems just to see if we get lucky.  I wouldn't count on it working for anything else, but it might.  These sorts of things tend to end up hyper-specialized.

Comment: It'd be nice if there was a way to adjust the ranking of questions the current user has already viewed.  You should already have that info to prevent the current user from counting over and over again in the view count, no?  For example, after using this new search tool a little bit and looking at everything that seems interesting, I'll keep seeing the same questions over and over for the next several hours.  Being able to "see stuff you haven't shown me yet" (outside of very annoying page management) would be nice.

Comment: This is awesome! What should we do with saved queries? I found this one to be fairly worthwhile http://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=f0a2baf2-fae6-4dde-9869-9761499ddd9e

Comment: @TravisJ if you have a winner, post an answer with it as a link and add some of your reasoning (if you feel like it).

Comment: @Servy unfortunately that data isn't really available just-in-time.  We have a few things that run over views *daily*, but those processes take hours.  The view counts on questions are stored just as simple `int`s, I can't add anything interesting to the search beyond that (that is `@AQViews` and `@UQViews` are all I can do).

Comment: @KevinMontrose Is there another mechanism of dealing with the, "I went to this page, it showed me some great stuff, I looked at it, and now it's just showing me the same stuff I already looked at instead of new great stuff" problem?  If that problem isn't solved people will probably just end up checking this every once in a while and then go right back to looking for questions using whatever they had been using before.

Comment: In theory, it changes because stuff ages out, gets downvoted/closed/deleted or gets answered, @Servy. Also, kind of a fail if you have to keep going back to the same question to click the button in the first place - the idea, after all, is just to give you a path to related questions immediately after you answer.

Comment: @Servy This search is also parameterized by the question/answer link provided; so it would be difficult to revisit the "same" search page unless you're posting multiple answers to the  same question (assuming the same basic flow as the previous experiment).

Comment: Probably the wording on the page should be changed a bit. When the page says, "*Additional* Ranking Function (multiplied with search score)", I assumed its optional. Otherwise the results are good. One more thing, can we boost a specific tag?

Comment: @ParagS.Chandakkar the tag has to be chosen automatically somehow (since this has to work for all users by default), it would be possible to boost tags by index now that I think about...  What are picturing doing?

Comment: @KevinMontrose It could consider just a few main tags, and could support some kind of blacklist. Depending on the question I use (independent of the search query), it messes up because of generic tags like `serialization` for example, and resulting on unwanted questions like a `python` one (since my main tag would actually be `java`). It could be workarounded with require main tag, but I think that boosting shared tags option is better, besides that side effects.

Comment: @falsarella Hmm, I could maybe add something that excludes shared tags that don't share certain criteria; dynamically building a blacklist basically.  Things like "more than X uses" or "user has answered in this tag before" would be possible.  Thoughts?

Comment: @KevinMontrose - What I would be interested to see is an overlap of the shared tag and required tag metrics. Perhaps some sort of combination if at all possible between required main and shared would be interesting.

Comment: @KevinMontrose Yeah, probably something involving user tag score would be great, but while I'm not interested on `python`, I might be interested on `angularjs`, which I recently didn't have any answers, but I was interested on it. Maybe something involving 'main user upvote tags'. I also like Travis's combination idea.

Comment: @falsarella & TravisJ alright, I'll see if I can't slam some new tag options out before dinner.

Comment: I would very much like the ability to limit the results by my favorite tags. Also whether or not the question *has an accepted answer*, rather than only *unanswered*. (A question with high votes, no accepted answer and answers with low votes is a sign of a question with a hard answer yet to be found.) By the way, have you considered simply exposing the customizability as a feature?

Comment: "These are the knobs we think matter most" But... but... what about me? Do I not *matter* to you? :(

Comment: @TravisJ more tag focused options added, [post edited to reflect them](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/289702/revisions).

Comment: @falsarella ^ more options per above.  Not exactly what was requested, but what I can provided practically.  Even these are tricky, and rather slow.

Comment: @Radiodef Limiting by favorite tags is an option we could provide, but isn't much use as default as most users have no favorite tags.  Choosing "0 answers" instead of "unanswered" is a matter of practicality; *most* questions that get 1 answer are truly answered, the edge (where a 2nd answer is needed) is something I'm willing to punt on for now.  More knobs in existing list views are being worked on in parallel, this exact interface is a little too generic for good performance though (which is why there's a throttle).

Comment: I'm with @jongware. It's not hard to find new questions to answer just by drinking from the firehose (coupled with a couple of email alerts for tags I particularly care about) but searching for duplicates is really not adequately supported in any fashion right now.

Comment: I have been speculating that the problem is not so much with the knobs as with the stuff in the index in the first place. Would it be possible to offer different indices as input? For example, I frequently find a duplicate with almost the same title, but it never turns up in the automatically generated list of (not so) probable duplicates. So an index of just the titles might be useful, at least for experimentation.

Comment: Maybe it also depend on the focus of the search per interest. Sometime i try to help newcomer, sometime to specific more accurate and "difficult" (that need good knowlegde of subject) question and sometime take the mood and pick one just because it "talk". Reading earlier comment, some hide question with few view/answer/post and i understand it in subject with huge quantity of (for example) new question. The search result will thus depend on this way of looking that is not generic to all search (so ranking formula will take different argument and weight of it).

Comment: What about an option for not matching questions that I already visited / had no new comment/answer/edit since my last visit?

Comment: @ValentinLorentz - In my opinion, that would require too much calculation to be efficient. In theory it is a nice idea, but in practice it presents several very large hurdles. For example, checking for visitation is basically only done in the views counter algorithm/feature. It would require a call to that for each question calculated as a possible match. The "new" aspect of the comment makes that part hard, and also checking each question for a comment which you made would require a join and that also increases both complexity and time. Same goes for editing. This is why it may be hard to do.

Comment: @TravisJ maybe we can limit the scope to recent question view by user (like 50 or 200, in fact more a multiple of question per page in search result), this will reduce the scope and associate with question timestamp offer a nearly similar behaviour. User could have thje choice but the consequence for him will be a longer latency (artificial mainly and announced like 1 sec per 10 question in history) to allow the system to breath if he will keep an huge (unecessairy) history list.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't have visit data in any easily query-able form.  The closest we have is some traffic analysis on about a 24 lag, which wouldn't be quick enough even if it were readily available in for searches.

Comment: I know this is a pipe dream but the single most useful filter to tell interesting Java questions apart from the "can you please do my homework" ones would be "question text doesn't contain the string `Scanner`". I don't mind answering questions for newbies (I quite like it actually), but I'm sick to the teeth with artificially constructed homework scenarios that have no relevance in real life.

Comment: rereading the question, something make me thing that this is a bit an evil's search because it generate a scoped 'think for me' result page. From one point, very interesting to show only what really could treat but on the other side, hidding rest of the world. This is a point that make me 'hate' google that return only partial (forget commercial/financial inner interest of google) hit that self validate a point of view. When using this kind of search, you loose a part of your objectivity by removing question with divergent comment/reply. (Sorry non technical and more ethic comment)

Comment: @NeronLeVelu I think the crucial difference is that with google you have no choice. If I understood it correctly, on SO this customised search would be a button you can press if you want to or not if you don't.

Comment: @biziclop you are right but in fact, even with the choice, people let the *reduce scope, good for me* option (easier and nearly often in same direction of my thought). And, it's purely a point of view for keeping my brain open to different people that are  thinking maybe the opposite way on question. Technically speaking it's a good and valuable feature.

Comment: For once, we get to reverse the usual. Even though the specific application happens to be SO, this is still a question about the correct technique(s) to write code to accomplish a specific goal. As such, it's really much more topical on SO than it is here.

Comment: It's probably getting ahead of things here, but it'd be nice if the testing page just grabbed (or had an option to) the last answer that I gave, so I don't have to go hunting for a link to give it...

Comment: There should be a way of giving shared framework tags higher importance than shared language tags, since it seems that almost no one actually puts the most descriptive tag first

Comment: This is probably a bit out of scope for this search, but if I input a question containing a primary tag with version in it (like asp.net-mvc-3) I'll get zero results most of the time. I understand why (that tag is old now), but it would be great if versioning tags could somehow belong to their "parent" (in this case asp.net-mvc), or even better if you could toggle that behaviour. I assume that this requires a site-wide feature request, but you never know..

Answer (score 70):

What I'm REALLY missing is a way to NEGATE some tag; for example I like to answer Java questions, but I like "pure" Java, not all of that framework configuration and similar questions. I would like a way to explicitly exclude them.

And an easy way to save and call my tag list with a single click from every page, like just over the tag suggestion on the left.

If this exists and I'm missing it, please enlighten me.

Comment: I've suggested the tag blacklist: [see discussion here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query/289787#comment174324_289702).

Comment: @falsarella sorry, it was buried into comments, and i looked only at answer.

But don't worry IF it gets included i don't care who get the glory xD

Comment: Oh, I just wanted to follow up the discussion to who else sees your awesome answer... Don't worry about the glory, let's keep colaborating: that's the main point over here!

Comment: I think it makes sense to not have that, because you would need to negate thousands of tags you are not interested in, [the backend might somewhat have performance issues or complexity complications](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query/289787#comment174396_289702), and it would also be per-user input, which currently depends only on user question link. But I'm not sure how the architecture works, I'm just wondering.

Comment: Maybe, as a way out, instead of NEGATING your unwanted tags, you should BOOST your wanted tags. Additionally, choose your input question carefully! Try thinking like in that perspective, that's the purpose of the new available tag-related variables. Probably it's a better paradigm when using elastic search.

Comment: @falsarella you are gonna negate only some tag, not a lot, I hope. Because if you are negating a lot, then maybe you just had picked up the wrong tag in the beginning. About system weight, it should be similar to multitag; the negation may even happen at client side...

Answer (score 38):

I like to look at newest questions when answering. Especially questions which have an upvote and are generating a good set of views.

This means that on https://stackoverflow.com/questions?sort=newest sometimes there aren't any candidates. I already have it paginated by 50, but it quickly becomes hard, and sometimes discouraging, to flip through 300 questions posted in the past hour before finding a candidate. Repeating this process is not very fun either, so I tend to just wait on the first page and refresh.

Using this approach, I created a query which was weighted by votes, then views, then time. I placed extra weight on votes (100 times), because I figured that I would rather look a post with 2 votes than with 150 views. Although, that changes depending on time, because newer is better in my opinion.

The main function in the query is

```
((@UQScore*100) + @UQViews ) / @UQSecondsOld
```

@UQScore is the unanswered question score
@UQViews is the unanswered question's views
@UQSecondsOld is the unanswered questions seconds since posting

I have tried this metric with several posts and have found it to produce quality results so far. The downside is that some of the results seem a little broad and I am not sure if that is a result of a failure in my metric or just new questions in general.

<strike>[Saved Query Link](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=f0a2baf2-fae6-4dde-9869-9761499ddd9e)</strike>
Updated (Widened time window to account for slightly more questions)
<strike>[Saved Query Link](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=924ee4fa-f453-4a8f-9057-da387bfb153f)</strike>
Updated using new tags metric (I like this version)
[Saved Query Link](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=10071cc7-33be-480f-a79a-0066b3fd0ac8)

Comment: I'm not receiving any result using your saved query. That seems.. Really curious? For reference, I used [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29522551/webapi2-performance-of-many-vs-single-controller).

Comment: I just used your query and found a question that seemed interesting and I answered it. Thanks Travis.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - That is strange. It seems to be a result of there not being a c# posts which match that. I believe it is a result of using the strict tag requirement somehow, and changing the tag requirement to be fuzzied produces results (try 4 for example). Each of the results includes the main tag (c#). I am not sure why the main tag would not have matched in that instance.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - It would seem that because the question you looked for was rather short and didn't contain many keywords, it did not have much to match up with that was asked in the past 5 hours.

Comment: @TravisJ: seems like it indeed, although the scores (and results) are still very poor. I suspect it has a lot to do with the fact that this question is about ASP.NET Web Api 2 but most questions in that tag don't have the C# tag. This interferes with the requirement of the primary tag.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - The question itself isn't very clear. I think if you chose a better candidate it would yield better results. Also keep in mind, sometimes there aren't very many good new questions :P I am sure we would all be happy if every new question required us to both reflect internally while learning something new and passing that on to the OP. Unfortunately most new questions inspire facepalm.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel - Also, as for the scores in the question link that metric is just a result of the provided function. The top voted question result http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29489693/generate-pdf-controlled-by-action-filters is actually answerable, contains some sample code, is at +2 at the moment, and is also related to web-api.

Comment: Used this and found 10 questions to answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 22):

#### [**See my query version here.**](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=f8da4530-0818-4934-b4b2-f9e88126522b)

- Fuzzy like query with default  values
- Require primary tag and boost other shared tags by 5
- Ranking function:

> ```
> (
>   @UserAnswerScoreInTagsCommon *
>   @UserAnswerCountInTagsCommon *
>   (abs(@UQScore) + 1) *
>   @UQViews
> ) / (
>   (@UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnUQ + @UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnAQ + 1) *
>   (@UserAnswerCountInTagsOnAQ + @UserAnswerCountInTagsOnUQ + 1) *
>   sqrt((abs(@UQScore) - @UQScore) + 1) *
>   sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(@UQSecondsOld)))
> )
> ```

---

#### Query explanation

In other words, the ranking function can be explained in these parts:

1. BOOSTING:

   1.1 The sum of my score on the tags in common should be as high as possible:

   `@UserAnswerScoreInTagsCommon`

   1.2 My answer count on the tags in common should also be as high as possible:

   `@UserAnswerCountInTagsCommon`

   1.3 The absolute score of the question being searched should be as high as possible:

   `(abs(@UQScore) + 1)`

   1.4 The question number of views should be as high as possible:

   `@UQViews`
2. UNBOOSTING:

   2.1 The sum of my score on the tags of both provided and searching questions should be as less as possible in contrast with 1.1, so it'll unboost when we have an uncommonality (it is kind of negating the tags not in common):

   `(@UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnUQ + @UserAnswerScoreInTagsOnAQ + 1)`

   2.2 My answer count on the tags of both provided and searching questions should be as less as possible in contrast with 1.2, so it'll unboost when we have an uncommonality (it is also kind of negating the tags not in common):

   `(@UserAnswerCountInTagsOnAQ + @UserAnswerCountInTagsOnUQ + 1)`

   2.3 The questions being searched with negative scores should have just a little unboost, because you could be a necromancer and revive it with a very good answer to a question everyone else rejected:

   `sqrt((abs(@UQScore) - @UQScore) + 1)`

   2.4 The old, almost tumbleweed, questions should have just a very tiny unboost, because you could be an excavator and make a good answer to a question everyone else have not drawn attention:

   `sqrt(sqrt(sqrt(@UQSecondsOld)))`

<sub>* The `+ 1`s are needed when the previous results on 0 to turn it to 1 and apply the other factor's weight, so the multiplication would break a tie to a lot of questions with different weights on other factors just because a question score of 0, for example.</sub>

---

In comparison to other queries:

- This one *doesn't require a strong wording match*, so it's **fuzzily open to different questions**
- This one *doesn't care that much to how new the question is*, **prioritizing tags and scores**
- This one [has found some **fairly elaborate answerable questions**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query/289787#comment175353_289787)

---

## Important

Please, also note that the question you provide to the query should be chosen carefully since it'll rely on it when searching for the next question. Try providing a good elaborate question containing the main tags you are looking for, and you'll probably get better results, independently of the query you're using.

Comment: The "Boost any shared tag" with boost of 5 seems to work quite well with your query also.

Comment: @JonasCz Thanks for sharing! I'll look into that! But I'd suggest you to use  `Require primary tag and boost other shared tags` with a boost of 5, as you suggested, but that requiring the primary tag.

Comment: I used this and found a fairly elaborate question that I could answer. +1

Answer (score 8):

SE is still underestimating the importance of edits.

I'm amazed that edits aren't factored into this at all. I'm not really an SO user, but if this is to be rolled out elsewhere, then edits *really* should count on other sites. Sometimes a question is unanswerable/shouldn't-be-answered before an edit.

"Last Activity" is closest, but I'm guessing that catches a lot more than editing.

I would propose that recent edits should be factored in, and more weight should be given to posts edited by other users than ones edited only by the OP.

Furthermore, it shouldn't be too hard to calculate significant edits vs. simple stylistic changes, and obviously the former should be given plenty of weight, whilst the latter shouldn't matter very much at all.

If you add edit parameters I'll take a shot at it. :)

Comment: Away from the code at the moment, I'll see if we have any edit information in the search index.  If we do, it will probably just be the last time an edit was made though.

Comment: I thought it was similar to Data SE where such queries would be possible. "Last Edit" is worth factoring in, but probably not with much weight if the details of the edit can't be analysed.

Comment: What's available in the search index is a greatly cut down view of the data available in our SQL dbs.  Data.SE uses SQL backups, not search indexes.

Comment: @KevinMontrose does that also mean it's not really a viable option?

Comment: Not really, unfortunately.

Answer (score 5):

[My version](https://stackoverflow.com/search/new-next-answer?savedQuery=79d7091b-fa37-49bc-bbc3-06c516888ca0)

- heavily depends on shared tags
- `( 2.5 * @UserAnswerScoreInTagsCommon)` checks if the question is related to those the user is good at answering
- `sqrt(@UQViews + (@UQScore * 2.5))` determines question quality
- there is a small decay factor based on the time since last activity

Answer (score 4):

I'd really like to (re)point out the lack of a possibility to negate some tags. I'm fairly active in PHP, JavaScript and MySQL, but if I receive questions including those tags that include tags outside my expertise, there is not much I can do.

Also, some times I am looking at good questions, you know, the kind of questions with meat around the bone written by a user with some rep (usually, but not always) and some times I prefer crawling through a couple of unanswered questions with small text trying to help out figure out what the problem is and at least raise the question quality with comments. So if I hadn't lost my magical wand, I'd love to have the ability to search next question to answer based on the users' reputation. Having the search score multiplied by how close the two users' reputation is could help see more similar questions.

I'll try to figure the math later if there's interest.