# Suggest questions the user can answer based on the user's history of asked, answer and voted questions and answers

Tags: discussion

I've been a Stack Overflow member for years now.  I see my reputation go up every so often.  I'd like to spend some time now and again answering questions, but I never find the questions that exploit the expertise I have gathered over the years.

The problem is that I see the last few questions asked for a particular subject, which I never seem to relate to.  My reputation is mostly from coming back to answer a question I had, but whose answer is not recorded on SO.

Instead, Stack Overflow should compute the questions a user is most likely to be able to answer based on the users previous question, answers, and voted questions and answers.

Comment: What, you mean something like this: [Help build a good "Find The Next Question To Answer" query](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/289702)?

Comment: I've still got http://stackoverflow.com/home/recommended/debug?userid=289086&subtab=needs-answer bookmarked. Adjust the userid param for your id.

Comment: also related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/254592/1159478 & http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/271128/1159478

Comment: Do you not look at questions under your favorite tags?

Comment: Not sure why this needed this frosty a reception in terms of downvotes? It's clearly a good, constructive idea. Not everyone can be expected to know the entire network and its features.

Comment: @MichaelT, The [new "recommended" tab](http://stackoverflow.com/?tab=recommended&subtab=needsanswer&noAnswersOnly=on&minScore=1) is better and more usable.

Comment: @JonasCz yep... its more a "I still have that bookmarked"