# Suggest questions to answer based on history

Tags: feature-request

I say the site should go through my answers and figure out based on tags (and maybe keywords) which unanswered questions I am most likely able to answer, then make those questions appear first. That way, I don't have to sift through pages of questions I can't answer to get to the ones I can. For the asker, this potentially means getting an answer sooner rather than later.

Comment: It's not like they're not trying: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the questions by tag. On the top right corner, there's the *search* box and you may add the name of the tag between brackets you want/need to filter e.g. [java], [ruby], [php], etc. You may use multiple tags to filter the questions, also you may have different tabs in your browser to search for different tags e.g. [java] in a tab, [ruby] in another.

Also, the fact you filter the questions by a tag doesn't mean you have the knowledge to answer all the questions there. You can search questions on a very wide tag like [java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java) or in a more specific technology like [git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/git).

Last but not least, there's an Unanswered tab for each tag. Select that tab and search questions as you want/need.

Comment: you should also include that one can subtract tags e.g. [java] -[jframe]

Answer (score -3):

When SO will write a script to figure out what you can answer and what not, and ask you those question, it could just be that that script will answer those questions by it self.