# User Option to Turn Off -- Thank you for contributing! [Answer Similar Questions]?

Tags: discussion, user-interface, answer-similar-questions

I'm not sure when the new pop-up that says **Thank you for contributing!  [Answer Similar Questions]** began, but I don't recall seeing it until recently. I'm all for improvements, but it would be nice if there were a configuration option or user preference to prevent things like this that take screen real-estate from propping up. It would be more acute for mobile users.

I don't know if that is easily doable, but the stack UI is fairly optimal and efficient without it and **Tags** make similar questions apparent already. Is there already some option that would allow the user to turn those notifications on/off? If not, can it be done without much grief? My only concern is that the latest neat feature to one, becomes an annoyance to another if there is no way to turn it off.

Don't take this the wrong way, I'm not knocking the feature, I'm just curious if as the interface grows, whether it might not make sense to provide user control to turn on/off things that take up screen space and are not part of the normal question/answer process?

Comment: Does it pop up again after you click to close it? I closed mine and haven't seen it again since - but maybe I just haven't posted enough answers lately.

Comment: I have seen it twice in the past 24 hours. Once on SuperUser and just a few minutes ago on SO. I'll have to drop another comment when I see it again on the same site. Maybe it's a per-site one-time-notice?

Comment: Possibly - I can see wanting to encourage users to explore questions on different sites depending on their field of expertise and their mood.

Comment: I just got it for the second time in a row answering a question on SO. This time I specifically clicked [x] to close it, so we will have to wait until the next answer to know if it is really gone for good.

Comment: "I'm not knocking the feature" Well, I am.

Comment: [It started fairly recently](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query) and is still experimental.

Answer (score 17):

Clicking the `x` on it already dismisses it for forever*.

I'm more curious that you saw it on Super User, it's not enabled there and I have no logs of it being displayed on a non-Stack Overflow site.  If it happens again, could you grab a screenshot (including url bar)?

<sub>*Technically it sets a preference.  The preference is not surfaced at the moment so you can't uncheck it, which makes it practically "dismiss forever".</sub>

Comment: Oh... I hit the X to close it for that specific question since I obsessively close things that look like popups on my browser, but I didn't want to make it go away entirely! I was curious to explore that feature later on when I had more time.

Comment: @rachel If we keep it, we'll expose the preference.  Probably also expose the result page as a link somewhere too.

Answer (score -2):

It seems like this should have a check for reputation.

Anyone with even a small amount of reputation should know how to find questions.

I don't even have *that* much reputation and it's still somewhat... awkward to see this popup. It comes across as somewhat condescending to me, like "you don't even know how to answer questions!"

Perhaps change the wording to be remove the "thanks" and simply say "Interested in similar questions? Click here to see similar, unanswered questions."

---

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Comment: The hope is that people who answer questions will be in a question answering mood (and mode) and will welcome a streamlined process to finding more questions to answer. The copy isn't supposed to be condescending and it isn't really about whether you know how to find more questions. Instead, the banner is supposed to give users a hook to keep answering questions if that's what they want to do next.

Comment: @JonEricson it comes across that way since I have over 150 answers. For someone brand new, it would be a lot less so.

Comment: I think that finding this condescending is a case of seriously reading too far into it. SO is essentially saying "we think we can find similar questions to this faster than you can, if you're interested", and in theory they should be right. I don't see anything condescending about that.