# Similar question?

Tags: bug, answer-similar-questions

After answering this question, the system suggested that I may answer similar questions: [How to handle generic classes / interfaces in a modular application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29845594/how-to-handle-generic-classes-interfaces-in-a-modular-application)?

The first one that was presented was this: https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=29845899

I somehow fail to see how those question are similar.

Comment: Answer Similar Questions is bad, very bad. I also saw one of these and [it showed me questions that are not at all similar](http://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=29843169). I suggest you avoid it. Just [turn it off](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/291051/user-option-to-turn-off-thank-you-for-contributing-answer-similar-questions)

Comment: Turning it off might be a quick fix but the problem still persists. If the algorithm fails to deliver decent work, this ought to get some attention in my opinion. If action should be taken then either improving the similar question feature or simply removing it should be put on the agenda, no?