# "Answer similar questions" needs to be smarter about broad tags

Tags: feature-request, answer-similar-questions

*I feel like this should be a comment/answer on a general feedback “question” for “Answer similar questions” since it's so narrow, but I couldn't find such a post.*

I just met the new “Answer similar questions” feature after [writing an answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29857787/can-i-get-a-texture-onto-my-second-cube/29885249#29885249) to a [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) question. So I thought, “[Ah, I've heard about this!](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query) Let's take it for a spin.”

I click.
Disappointment.

[The results](https://stackoverflow.com/search/next-answer?answerid=29885249) are indistinguishable from a sampling of [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript) questions — they're all of the common sort “how do I do this with this JavaScript library”, and of course I don't happen to know any of those libraries.

On the other hand, if I'd gotten a list of [webgl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webgl) or [texture-mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/texture-mapping) questions, perhaps with extra similarity-magic, I'd much more likely have one to answer — perhaps even with some of the context and research I already pulled up for the first answer!

So, **please show me only questions that have some evident similarity beyond the primary tag**, at least when the tag is one which is so broad as [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript). The simplest implementation that comes to mind is to just drop the primary tag (given some sort of condition for breadth).

Comment: Hmm.  For a completely new user (who has answered their first question), the broadness of the primary tag might be good?  Or maybe some kind of "tag power", where we determine how "strong" a given tag is to people answering in a clusters?  Ie, P(you'd answer a javascript question | you answered a different javascript question) vs P(you'd answer a webgl question | you answered a different webgl question) or something?  With "strong" tags (that cause user clumping) being followed more than weak tags?