# Would it be feasible to improve question discoverability?

Tags: feature-request

I have seen some posts about implementing difficulty tiers into questions, usually citing the need for people to answer questions at their own skill level.

**I want to help contribute, but have a hard time finding any questions I feel confident answering (due to low skill level).**

Is there a good way to deliver questions someone could probably answer to their inbox? My thinking is that the monkey two rungs above you on the ladder can help you, and you can help the monkey a rung below you.

Is the current system good enough? Should less-skilled developers simply never contribute? Would a difficulty system need to be in place?

Thanks for reading!

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254592/how-do-active-answerers-find-questions-to-answer

Comment: related: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query

Comment: that last link is relevant for the discussion, that link to the specific search page is no longer live.