# What happened to the 'Find your next answer' query?

Tags: support

In April 2015, I remember using the [query tool on this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289702/help-build-a-good-find-the-next-question-to-answer-query) to find questions that needed answers. However, it now returns a 404.

Has this tool been implemented somewhere else, or are there any plans to do so, or are the results now shown by default on the home tab? I don't  necessarily want the ability to customise the query, but the list of questions it produced were really good.

Comment: Scrapped along with the recommended tab... :(

Comment: @Braiam oh. Is there a discussion about this on Meta, or a blog post somewhere?

Comment: Read the revision history http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/289702/revisions

Comment: @Braiam as far as I can see, while that says that they've disabled the interface to which the question links, they will be implementing the chosen algorithm somewhere on the site.

Comment: @Blowski I agree with your inference. I nearly posted that update here as an answer, but read this: _"The actual "next answer suggestion"-feature remains disabled while final adjustments are made (exposing the dismissal setting, tweaks around answer flow, changes to prompting logic, etc.).  I'll probably be posting again in the coming weeks with the final-ish design._" 

So I'm just expecting someone more knowledgable would come by and post a more recent update (than June 11th)