# "Questions you might be able to answer" kind of recommendation

Tags: feature-request, questions, recommendation-questions

Based on various parameters like:

1. What kind of questions a user has answered previously
2. What kind of questions does a user follow regularly and engages in with comments, edits, documentation, etc.
3. Several others

How about a recommendation for the user to answer some possible questions? I am not aware if this feature is already there. Q&A sites like [Quora](https://www.quora.com/) already have this feature and have been proven quite successful and useful. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: I'm not necessarily against it, but isn't that basically what a tag is?  I'm an expert at Android, I can click on the Android tag and see many questions I could probably answer.  I'm not sure what value that gives, unless there's something more to it-  like picking questions of particularly high value that need answering somewhow

Comment: although tags serve the purpose in coarse level.. wouldn't it be better to fine tune recommendations? StackExchange keeps publishing data analytics on it's usage.. I think this particular feature would prove useful in terms of their engineering as well as user experience..

Comment: I find those types of analytics pretty creepy and prefer they not be performed on me

Comment: @GabeSechan http://stackoverflow.com/users/tag-future/current

Comment: I thought they experimented with this a while ago, back when they still cared about Q&A.  After answering a question you could open a list of questions that the system thought you could answer.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/286912/what-is-the-new-answer-similar-questions-feature-for